# how to match partial search query from 2 columns in lumen

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I have a table called stores with a name and address column.

I have a store record with name; "Target" and address; "112 W 34th St., New York, NY 10120, United States".

**My Expectation:**

querying the database for "Target NY" should return the above record

**Current Result:**

the database query can't find the record.

**What I have tried**:

```
$stores = DB::table('stores')
        ->where('name', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('address', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->get();
```

the above query is unable to find the record.

I have also tried concatenating the query on both columns

```
 $stores = DB::select("
            SELECT *
            FROM stores
            WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', address) LIKE '%".$query."%'
           ");
```

the example above can't find the record as well.

I don't want to believe that it's impossible to query the table as i want.

and if it's possible to perform that query, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH` and `AGAINST` for the search name and address string.

```
$stores = DB::select("
    SELECT *
    FROM stores
    WHERE MATCH(name, address) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   ", [$query]);
```

**Notes :** In order to use the `MATCH` function, you'll need to have a `full-text index` set up on the name and address columns.

You can setup by this query inside sql : `ALTER TABLE stores ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_index (name, address);`

Comment: i would give it a try, are there any implications of setting up full-text index on columns?

Comment: No you only need to fire sql query to convert columns into index.
`ALTER TABLE stores ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_index (name, address);`

Comment: doing this returns the expected result, but it also return a target with the address "                "address": "2580 Shearn St, Houston, TX 77007, United States",", it just prioritizes the on wit NY first

Comment: also searching "Target TX", still returns the "Target " with the NY address